# java - how to ignore a class or method only when tests are running

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I am searching for a way to ignore static method calls when tests are running.

My test runner is robolectric. I have some methods i don't want to execute when a test is executing.  Is there any annotation or technique i can use?

My utility class i need ignored simply looks like this:

```
public class FabicTrackerUtils {

    private static void trackLoginActivity(LoginEvent loginEvent) {
        //...
        Answers.getInstance().logLogin(loginEvent);
    }

    private static void trackPaymentsActivity(PaymentEvent paymentEvent) {
        //...
        Answers.getInstance().logLogin(paymentEvent);
    }
}
```

I want to avoid having test conditionals, e.g. `if(!robolectricTest)` all over my production code's methods.

Comment: What this suggests to me is that you should be injecting a fake `Answers` instance in your tests that does no logging, instead of having a static `Answers.getInstance()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on @Louis' comment, your should be using dependency injection, e.g. by having method signatures like these:

```
private static void trackLoginActivity(LoginEvent loginEvent, Answers answers) {
    //...
    answers.logLogin(loginEvent);
}
```

An alternative, since the `Answers` instance looks like a singleton, is to inject the object as an instance variable, e.g.:

```
public class FabicTrackerUtils {
    private Answers answers;

    public FabicTrackerUtils(Answers answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    private static void trackLoginActivity(LoginEvent loginEvent) {
        //...
        answers.logLogin(loginEvent);
    }
}
```

This is assuming that the test can instantiate `FabicTrackerUtils` and pass in a mocked `Answers` instance. If this is not possible, you'd add an accessor method to `FabicTrackerUtils`:

```
public class FabicTrackerUtils {
    private Answers answers;

    public setAnswers(Answers answers) {
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    private static void trackLoginActivity(LoginEvent loginEvent) {
        //...
        answers.logLogin(loginEvent);
    }
}
```

Comment: great answer. and this link solidified it. https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-testing-using-dagger-2-mockito-and-a-custom-junit-rule-c8487ed01b56#.vu3i4eqnj